My cat attacks me then hides
My cat isn't aggressive, she has all her needs met but sometimes she runs away and hides under our dresser. Sometimes she'll attack me and then run away to hide. Am I making her scared somehow? I've never hit her or even pushed her when she attacks me so this worries me. Could this be boredom? If so how do I fix it

How old is she? She may just be playing with you as she would another cat, swat in order to provoke an entertaining chase/wrestle. At a year and a half, my Siamese used to pounce my ankles when she was in a playful mood.

This sounds like normal play behavior for cats. If she was afraid of you, she probably wouldn't play with you like this.
The best way to fix it is to divert this play to something less painful that your feet. A wand with a toy tied to a long string would make a good play target or maybe a small plush ball you can roll in her direction.
Please make sure that your cat cannot swallow long strings when playing because that can be lethal. Home-made pom-poms or just length of knitting yarn are no suitable cat toys.
